# Relationship between the line with gradient -1 and (-1/3) issue with tan(theta)=m argument - PLEASE HELP!

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vector-analysis

I was tutoring a student today and they asked a very interesting question while we were looking at the $tan(\theta)=m$ formula for the angle of inclination/the angle with the positive direction of the x-axis and a line with gradient $m$.

We considered the fact that when $m=-1$, the angle made with the positive direction of the x-axis is $$(180-45)^\circ=135^\circ$$

But from here, consider it as an angle from the negative direction of the x-axis:
He stated that if $-1$ has angle $45^\circ$, then $m=\frac{-1}{3}$ should have angle equal to $\frac{1}{3}*45^\circ=15^\circ$ from the negative direction of the x-axis which would be $(180-15)^\circ=165^\circ$ from the positive direction of the x-axis.

Why does plugging this same problem into the $tan(\theta)=m$ where $m=\frac{-1}{3}$ give us a different answer?

Comment: I've read that the relationship between the gradient and angle is not linear, but I don't understand why it wouldn't be when we simply consider what it is

Comment: Have you looked at a graph of tan? Does it look linear? Or do you know the addition formula for tan (i.e., $\text{tan}(x+y)=\dots$)? Does it look like a linear equation?

Comment: Absolutely: I know that tan isn't linear, but why does this not work? Ignore the tan argument until the last step, I'm instead looking for an explanation about why their argument is wrong